# Change specific repeating element in .xml using Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml

I have the following .xml file which I like to manipulate:

```
<html>
  <A>
    <B>
      <C>
        <D>
          <TYPE>
            <NUMBER>7297</NUMBER>
            <DATA />
          </TYPE>
          <TYPE>
            <NUMBER>7721</NUMBER>
            <DATA>A=1,B=2,C=3,</DATA>
          </TYPE>
        </D>
      </C>
    </B>
  </A>
</html>
```

I want to change the text inside the `<DATA>` that lies under the `<NUMBER>7721</NUMBER>` element. How do I do that? If I use `find()` or `findtext()` it is only able to point to the first match.

Comment: "I want to change the text inside the that lies under the 7721." What does that mean? You seem to have left out a word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XPath is great for this kind of stuff. `//TYPE[NUMBER='7721' and DATA]` will find all the TYPE nodes that have at least one NUMBER child with text '7721' and at least one DATA child:

```
from lxml import etree

xmlstr = """<html>
  <A>
    <B>
      <C>
        <D>
          <TYPE>
            <NUMBER>7297</NUMBER>
            <DATA />
          </TYPE>
          <TYPE>
            <NUMBER>7721</NUMBER>
            <DATA>A=1,B=2,C=3,</DATA>
          </TYPE>
        </D>
      </C>
    </B>
  </A>
</html>"""

html_element = etree.fromstring(xmlstr)

# find all the TYPE nodes that have NUMBER=7721 and DATA nodes
type_nodes = html_element.xpath("//TYPE[NUMBER='7721' and DATA]")

# the for loop is probably superfluous, but who knows, there might be more than one!
for t in type_nodes:
    d = t.find('DATA')
    # example: append spamandeggs to the end of the data text
    if d.text is None:
        d.text = 'spamandeggs'
    else:
        d.text += 'spamandeggs'
print etree.tostring(html_element)
```

Outputs:

```
<html>
  <A>
    <B>
      <C>
        <D>
          <TYPE>
            <NUMBER>7297</NUMBER>
            <DATA/>
          </TYPE>
          <TYPE>
            <NUMBER>7721</NUMBER>
            <DATA>A=1,B=2,C=3,spamandeggs</DATA>
          </TYPE>
        </D>
      </C>
    </B>
  </A>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I only want to change the second data path <DATA>A=1,B=2,C=3,</DATA> so I'm thinking about pinpointing it by using the <NUMBER>7721</NUMBER> instead of the "emptiness" of the <DATA>

Comment: @user1546610 Then you just have to change the xpath! I've edited my answer